# Eclipse Juno is not starting in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am getting Error to open Eclipse. i am using Eclipse Juno 64 bit on window 7 64 bit
the log of Eclipse is

```
 !SESSION 2012-10-22 11:42:40.638 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
    java.version=1.7.0
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2012-10-22 11:42:48.527
    !MESSAGE [SCR] Exception while activating instance org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager@7e3e5dbe of component org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme  
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use eclipse 64bit you also need a 64bit java runtime (and vice versa).
I personally wouldn't recommend it as both java and eclipse seem to be instable in their 64bit versions. Perhaps it got better, but I switched back to 32bit after using 64bit for a while.